# Стоит ли использовать прямую вставку изображений (src="data:image/png...) на страницу?

Tags: php, графика, оптимизация-сайтов

Есть страница с множеством оптимизированной графики (~10мб). Есть вариант вставить всю эту графику напрямую по типу: `<img src="data:image/png;..."`.

По сути получиться 1 огромный запрос размером в ~10-12мб.

Вопрос: не будет ли побочных эффектов от такой оптимизации?

Если посоветуете другие методы оптимизации для моего случая, то так же буду благодарен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут оптимизацией даже и не пахнет. Скорее наоборот.

1) У вас страница не сможет до конца загрузиться пока не загрузиться код с картинкой. Будет большой реквест.

2) Этот код априори будет тяжелее чем эта-же картинка в формате `png` или `jpg`.

3) Картинки один раз загрузятся - дальше попадут в кеш, что убирает нагрузку при повторном запросе пользователя.

4) Если использовать серверные оптимизации, то для сервера отдавать кучу мелких изображений не будет никаких проблем.

Отсюда вывод: не надо использовать `data:image/png;` тем более тяжелые, лучше используйте картинки.

Answer (score 2):

В смысле в base64 вставить в хтмл? Это значительно увеличит размер изображений, и уменьшит кол-во обращений к серверу. Так имеет смысл поступать с совсем не большими изображениями, может даже улучшить скорость загрузки.
По оптимизации сложно что-то конкретное сказать, т.к способы могут быть разными. Уменьшить копии изображений и по клику показывать целиком. Или загружать по мере скроллинга страницы.

Сам пользуюсь вот этим: http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/
Прост в использовании, картинки можно листать в т.ч с клавиатуры, к каждой добавить описание. Вот пример кода из документации:

```
<a href="images/examples/image-3.jpg" rel="lightbox[plants]" 
title="Click on the right side of the image to move forward.">
<img src="images/examples/thumb-3.jpg" 
alt="Plants: image 1 0f 4 thumb" /></a>
```